# uncaught syntax error : unexpected token

Tags: javascript

im making a pong clone with js and i am using windows.onload fucnction and it says that there is a period that isn't supposed to be there idk where they could be talking about and it says its on the windows.onload function line

```html
<canvas id="pg" width = "800" height = "600">
  <script>
    var c;
    var cc;
    var ballx = 50;
    var bally = 50;
    var

    window.onload = function(){
      c = document.getElementById("pg");
      cc = c.getContext("2d");
      
      var fps = 180;
      setInterval(draw,1000/fps)
    }
    function draw(){
      ballx += 1.5;
      cc.fillStyle = "black";
      cc.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
      cc.fillStyle = "white";
      cc.fillRect(ballx,bally,10,10);
      cc.fillRect(10,210,100,25);
    }
  </script>
</canvas>
```

Comment: You seem to have a stray var on the fifth line of your script.

Comment: yea i was creating one when i realized that it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You have left an empty var declaration at line 5 of your script tag. This breaks the window.onload event callback.